# How to check if the mouse is down in AceEditor

Tags: ace-editor

I run computationally expensive code when the cursor changes and this becomes obvious when the user is selecting a lot of text.

I'd like to know if the mouse is down or up so I can ignore the cursor change events if the user is dragging. When they let go of the mouse down button I can run my code on mouse up or on cursor change events when the mouse is up.

Is there a way to tell if the mouse is down in ace editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `editor.$mouseHandler.isMousePressed` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event listeners on ace editor. The mousedown event should help you in this case.

```
editor.on("mousedown", function () {
      console.log("mouse down");
});
```